# Как Assert.assertThat() в Junit делает сравнение результатов теста?

Tags: java, junit

У меня тест в конце которого проверка двух объектов на равенство:

```
assertThat(result, is(proposal1));
```

И мне падает ошибка хотя `Expected` и `Actual` в логе показаны одинаковыми:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <Proposal{header='header_1', author='author', create=2017-05-17 14:23:39.807, ulrPropose='url_4', urlRecruiter='url'}>
     but: was <Proposal{header='header_1', author='author', create=2017-05-17 14:23:39.807, ulrPropose='url_4', urlRecruiter='url'}>
Expected :is <Proposal{header='header_1', author='author', create=2017-05-17 14:23:39.807, ulrPropose='url_4', urlRecruiter='url'}>

Actual   :<Proposal{header='header_1', author='author', create=2017-05-17 14:23:39.807, ulrPropose='url_4', urlRecruiter='url'}>
```

Разве два объекта с одинаковым состояние не должны проходить `assertThat`???

Как мне это поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы объекты корректно сравнивались на равенство нужно переопределить метод [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) и реализовать логику сравнения по нужным полям.

Если `equals` не переопределен, то будет использоваться реализация по умолчанию в который равными считаются только ссылки на один и тот же объект. Совпадение значений полей роли не играет.

Из документации:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only **if x and y refer to the same object** (x == y has the value true).

Если `equals` переопределен, то нужно искать ошибку в реализации метода.

**UPDATE (по JUnit):** Junit также не выполняет сверку полей в данном случае:

[`assertThat`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) обращается к переданному `matcher`-у, в данном случае `is`

> Asserts that actual satisfies the condition specified by matcher.

[`is`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#is(T)) обращается к `equalTo`:

> A shortcut to the frequently used is(equalTo(x)).

[`equalTo`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#equalTo(T)) использует `equals` с предпроверкой на `null`:

> Creates a matcher that matches when the examined object is logically equal to the specified operand, as determined by calling the **`Object.equals(java.lang.Object)`** method on the examined object.

Comment: разве `Asster.assertThat` не решает это сам?

Comment: @Павел нет, он использует `is`, а тот использует `equals`.

Comment: Да точно вы правы посмотрел все так и есть. Спасибо.